# gzip decompress a property in a json file using bash

Tags: json, bash, base64, jq, gunzip

I have to verify that the base64 encoded and gzipped contents of a property in a json file are the same as the raw ones using bash.

I have been able to extract the property using jq:

```
cat src/my-file.json | jq '.Attachment[] | .Contents["@Value"] | @base64d'
```

I have tried using `gzip` to decompress this using `@gzipd` filter

> jq: error (at :798): gzipd is not a valid format

and piping the value to `gunzip` command:

> gunzip: unknown compression format

I have tried writing the contents to a file named test.gz and then using `gunzip`.

```
cat src/my-file.json | jq '.Attachment[] | .Contents["@Value"] | @base64d' > test.gz
```

> gunzip: test.gz: not in gzip format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [#1931](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1931):

> Let `$B` be an arbitrary base64 string, then `$B | @base64d` is undefined if `base64 -D <<< $B` is not a valid UTF-8 string.

Below is a quick workaround; output raw base64 string and decode it using `base64` utility:

```
jq -r '.Attachment[] | .Contents["@Value"]' src/my-file.json | base64 -d | gunzip
```